# Issue installing spacyr on R 4.2

Tags: r, spacy, failed-installation

I am having trouble installing spacyr on R version 4.2. What is strange is that I've used this package in the past just fine. The installation is pretty basic. Per their site you do the following:

```py
install.packages("spacyr")
library("spacyr")
spacy_install()
```

However, when I run `spacy_install()` I get the error: `Error: one or more Python packages failed to install [error code 1]` with the traceback:

```
5.
stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
4.
stopf(fmt, result)
3.
reticulate::conda_install(envname, packages, pip = pip, conda = conda)
2.
process_spacy_installation_conda(conda, version, lang_models, 
python_version, prompt, envname = envname, pip = pip)
1.
spacy_install()
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling spacyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

I tried more things like `install_miniconda()` (see the following code block)

```
install.packages('spacyr')
spacyr:::install_miniconda()
library(spacyr);spacy_install(prompt = FALSE)
```

But I was still unable to use spaCy.

I deleted my miniconda folder in my home directory and then ran the above code and I was able to use spaCy.